# 403 Forbidden - A potentially unsafe operation has been detected in your request to this site - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, opencart

I have a form which has dynamically generated form fields. In this case, 2661  form inputs are generated and when submitting the form data (`POST`) request, I can see `uploading x%` in Google chrome. There is no file input on the form. Once uploading reaches 100% it throws a 403 error

```
403 Forbidden - A potentially unsafe operation has been detected in your request to this site.
```

Have researched on google and tried enabling `mod_security` via `.htaccess`but nothing changed.
I can only see Wordfence solutions which are not applicable to my case.
I'm using Plesk, PHP 7.4, OpenCart 3.x
Any solution for this?

Comment: the `uploading` part can be normal, it also appears for (long) textarea texts, and basically its uploading text, and a file is also text ;) Did you check upload limits for php-configuration ? check network tab how big the request is

Comment: The upload limits are set at 999M, let me check the size of request

Comment: the request is `323 B` that is small enough I believe

Comment: it may have to do with directory/file permissions, to keep one thing out: Does it work when using only 1 input ?

Comment: other forms on the same server with fewer inputs are working well, except this one

Comment: Does the object you upload happen to contain HTML or Javascript? You may be running into cross-site-scripting (XSS) prevention measures.

Comment: no HTML/javascript , most values are 0/1

Comment: Apache logs (LogLevel debug) and php logs say anything?